# Titanium mobile parse json response

Tags: json, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to get the DishName from this json string which is being returned from my php api.

The json string is

```
["Spicy.com Specials",{"CatID":31,"CatName":"Spicy.com Specials","DishName":"Kashmiri Chicken","DishID":52,"DishDesc":"Cooked with lychees and banana in a lovely sweet and creamy sauce","DishPrice":6.99,"CatDescription":" "},{"CatID":31,"CatName":"Spicy.com Specials","DishName":"Telapia Fish","DishID":51,"DishDesc":"Lightly spiced fillet, a very popular white fish made with peppers, onions and spices in medium sauce","DishPrice":6.99,"CatDescription":" "},
```

My titanium code is

```
var cats = eval('('+this.responseText+')');
alert(cats[0]);
```

This get's me 'Foo.com Specials' however I need the DishName, any help would be much appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Please be sure to mark one of the replies as correct.

Answer (score 5):

You will actually get back a JSON string, not a JSON object. There is a build in feature for parsing the JSON string to JSON object:

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Getting the DishName then is easy:

```
var dishname = response[0].DishName;
```

*Note: Your currently displayed JSON seems to be incomplete, or otherwise it is an invalid JSON object.*

Comment: Thank you very much.  Really needed that part about how to get the dishname.

Answer (score 2):

First thing your JSON response is not valid. You can validate your JOSN string [Online here](http://jsonlint.com/).

You can parse your JSON response by built in method `JSON.parse()`.

Sample code:-

```
yourLoader.onload = function()
{
    var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var dishname = response[0].DishName;

    Ti.API.log('Your Dish Name:'+dishname);     
}
```